# How can I tell what PCIe USB 3.0 cards are compatible with NAS4Free / FreeBSD?

Tags: drivers, freebsd, pci-express, usb-3

I have [NAS4Free](http://www.nas4free.org/) running on an [HP ProLiant Microserver G7 N40L/N54L](http://n40l.wikia.com/wiki/HP_MicroServer_N40L_Wiki). The Microserver only has USB 2.0 ports, so I’m thinking of purchasing a PCIe card so I can use a USB 3.0 hard drive at full speed. How can I tell what cards are compatible?

I figure the yes/no in each case will depend on the chipset the card uses. From my research so far, it looks like it’s the [xHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHCI) driver that talks to the USB controller. (See [17.4. USB Storage Devices](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/usb-disks.html), and the [`xhci` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xhci).)

Is this something that even needs to be checked? Or do all USB 3.0 chipsets have to present a uniform interface, such that a single generic driver (xhci) handles all?

If there are compatibility issues, does NAS4Free support all the chipsets that FreeBSD does? The latest NAS4Free, 10.1.0.2, is based on FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue (I now have a functional USB3 add-in card in my NAS4Free box). If someone else can explain how to tell which cards work in general, I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Based on [FreeBSD Compatible USB 3.0 PCIe Cards](https://www.ateamsystems.com/tech-blog/freebsd-compatible-usb-3-0-pcie-cards/), I installed a [Syba 4 Port USB 3.0 PCI-e 2.0 x1 Card (SD-PEX20137)](http://www.sybausa.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=64_77_90&product_id=227). It works once I remembered to connect the Molex power.

I was hoping I could also use the card to boot from my USB3 thumb drive, but apparently that's a no-go.

> you cannot boot via the BIOS on any device that is an ‘add-in’ device, unless it is a PCI card that also contains an option ROM...
>
> Unfortunately, I am not aware of any USB 3.0 add-in cards which have their own Option ROMs that allow you to boot from their USB 3.0 ports.

source: [Why can't I boot from the USB 3.0 ports on my PCI add-in card?](http://rmprepusb.blogspot.com/2014/05/why-cant-i-boot-from-usb-30-ports-on-my.html)

Comment: FWIW, I'm doing a spot of testing and bought a couple of random USB 3.0 cards from eBay, one with the VIA chipset, and another with the Reneas chipset. The VIA arrived first and I plugged it into the obvious x1 slot and it wasn't bootable, but when the Reneas arrived I had to pop it into another slot and discovered it was bootable. Swapping the cards made the VIA bootable and the Reneas non-bootable, showing it was the slot, not the cards.

Comment: (Cont'd) This may (probably) be a quirk of my motherboard (a Gigabyte 990FXA-UD5 with a built-in Etron USB 3.0 controller), but I thought it worth mentioning that people stumbling across this in the future might want to try using different slots.